# c# DataContractJsonSerializer returns null

Tags: c#, json, serialization, datacontractjsonserializer

Hello I have this code:

trough HttpClient I recieve this json string:

```
{"group":3,"data":[{"count":1,"providerName":"BetaDigital","providerNo":12},{"count":139,"providerName":"Free to air","providerNo":1}]}


            var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(GroupProvider));
            var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonString));

            var data = (GroupProvider) serializer.ReadObject(ms);
```

Then I have this classes:

```
[DataContract]
public class GroupProvider 
{
    public int Group { get; set; }
    public DataGroupProvider[] data { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class DataGroupProvider 
{

    public int Count { get; set; }
    public string ProviderName { get; set; }
    public int ProviderNo { get; set; }
}
```

Problem is, that only the Group is filled and the DataGroupProvider is null..

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

As described in the [Data Contract Basics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733127(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_0), you either don't put `DataContract` attribute in which case every public property or field will be considered (but note that the names should match exactly) or put `DataContract` attribute and then you need to explicitly mark the members that you want to be considered with `DataMember` attribute. The latter also allows you to change the name mapping.

So, your sample JSon can be deserialized with either this data model (note the property name casing):

```
public class GroupProvider
{
    public int group { get; set; }
    public DataGroupProvider[] data { get; set; }
}

public class DataGroupProvider
{
    public int count { get; set; }
    public string providerName { get; set; }
    public int providerNo { get; set; }
}
```

or keeping your current property names:

```
[DataContract]
public class GroupProvider
{
    [DataMember(Name = "group")]
    public int Group { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public DataGroupProvider[] data { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class DataGroupProvider
{
    [DataMember(Name = "count")]
    public int Count { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "providerName")]
    public string ProviderName { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "providerNo")]
    public int ProviderNo { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set an DataMember-Attribute like this:

```
[DataContract]
public class GroupProvider
{
    [DataMember]
    public int Group { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public DataGroupProvider[] data { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class DataGroupProvider
{

    [DataMember]
    public int Count { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string ProviderName { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int ProviderNo { get; set; }
}
```

Then change your JSON to a correct one:

`var str ="{\"Group\":3,\"data\":[{\"Count\":1,\"ProviderName\":\"BetaDigital\",\"ProviderNo\":12},{\"Count\":139,\"ProviderName\":\"Free to air\",\"ProviderNo\":1}]}";`

JSON-Data is **CaseSensitive**